# Azure Data Factory - Default sorting order of Copy Data task?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory, parquet

We stumbled upon an interesting little issue that has me stumped. In Azure Data Factory, we import parquet files into SQL Server. The parquet file is generated from another SQL database hosted in Azure. The source table has a clustered index on the `Key` column. On top of this table is a view that sorts the *columns* in a different order, but there is no `ORDER BY` clause on it. The target table (extract) has no indexes on it.

I generated a number of different files from this table, and all of them end up showing sorted by the `Key` column both in the parquet file, as well as in the target table.

We manipulated the values of a few rows in the `Description` column to contain a long description. In the physical source table, this column is the last column in the table. In the view, it's brought in as the 3rd column, which maps accordingly in the target table.

Viewing the parquet file, the rows are ordered by the `Key` column (I.e. -1003, -1002, 1, 2, 3). However, when importing the data into SQL Server (using a mapping based on the order of the columns in the parquet file), the order of the rows suddenly switched (-1003, -1002, 1, 18, 19..30, 2).

I tried adding a clustered index on the target table sorting by `Key ASC` (which should determine the physical order on disc) and reloaded the file, but that didn't change anything, even after updating the statistics for the table.

When I check the query execution plan, it simply performs a table scan (this could be due to the file only containing 50 rows or so, and thus it being faster for SQL Server to do a table scan instead of sing the index).

How would we be able to determine the order in which the `Copy Data` task in ADF ingests the data, or somehow force it to be sorted by `Key`?

Comment: Tables are inherently unordered. The only way to get a guaranteed order for any `SELECT` query is to apply an `ORDER BY` to that query.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Sure. But wouldn't a clustered determine the physical sort order of the table?

Comment: The clustered index determines a partially logical, partially physical ordering of pages and rows. But SQL Server is under *no* obligation to scan a table in that order and return rows in that order.

Comment: No, a clustered index does not guarantee ordering of results. That's why [order by is required](https://www.dbdelta.com/order-by-is-required/) in the outermost `SELECT` query.

Comment: @DanGuzman and @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Fair enough, and duly noted. So the result I see might not be caused by the order in which ADF processed the data, but simply by how SQL Server returns the rows? I attempted to resolve this by using a `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT !))`, but that again just seems to order it by the exact order the select orders it. I'm thinking I could probably force it to order by `Key`, but seeing future files might not have their rows ordered by the `Key`, it could still lead to differences.

Comment: For deterministic ordering (assuming data are unchanged), you'll need to order by a unique column(s).